# How to add styling to a single input in a form_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I'm using the rails framework with HAML and I have bootstrap setup. How would I format the field inputs seperately. I want the input field for name to be 60% of the screen float left and the input for price to be 25% of the screen and float right.

I guess i'm asking how do i add classes to single inputs in a form_for.
Thanks

```
= form_for @product,:url => products_path, :html => { :id => "fileupload", :multipart => true } do |f| 
  %p
    = f.label :name
    = f.text_field :name # i want to format this
  %p
    = f.label :price
    = f.text_field :price
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

you can add a class to any form helper and use CSS to format it:

```
= f.text_field :name, class: 'your_class' # i want to format this
```

of cause you can also set a style option directly, but it is recommended to separate content and styling. So don't

```
= f.text_field :name, style: 'float: left; width: 60%; display: block' # i want to format this
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I can't mark you correct for another 3 minutes.

Comment: for `simple_form` use: `, input_html: {style: 'direction: ltr;'}`

Comment: better: for `simple_form` use: `, input_html: {class: 'your_class'}`

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= f.password_field :password, class: "your style class", style: "display: block;" %>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**